# How can split biggest array from MySql with Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a big problem: there will be a page, on my website, whit a form where user can select date and other options to view earthquakes occured in the world.

The problem is if, for example, user can views quakes occured in last year.
This option will return a very big array and i think that slow down the loading and maybe browser could have a limit for file.

So how can i split the big array ?

**PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM earthquakes WHERE milliseconds > 0";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // fetches a result row as an associative array
       $result[] = $row;
   }
   mysqli_free_result($result);
}

echo json_encode($result); // return value of $result
mysqli_close($con); // close connection with database
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "database-sismico.php?"+query,
    success: function (result) { //Performs an async AJAX request
        if (result) {

        }
        else {
            //will print alert to advice user that there aren't quakes
        }
    },
    dataType:"json"
});
```

Can you suggest me something ?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english...

Comment: Either slice the array in the SQL code by selecting TOP X and save the index somwehere. Or load the entire array to the website and slice it there, before rendering the result.

Comment: Give them the first 10 and make a link for the next 10. Look at pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this question is a bit broad, there is some fairly standard advice I can give that should help point you in the right direction.

In general, when you have some list of something, and that list is possibly very large, a common technique is to implement "[pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination#Pagination_in_electronic_display)". Literally, turn it into multiple pages.

The general approach to this is to in some way pass in a page parameter (usually in the query string) and then use that to fetch a certain amount of results.

On the query side, you can do this by using `LIMIT` to set a maximum, and then use the page parameter to set an `OFFSET`.

For example, if you are going to show 200 results per page, then your `LIMIT` is 200. If you are on page 3, then you would set the offset as `(page-1)*max`, which would be `(3-1)*200` or `400`. This will get the results starting from result 400 and getting 200.

```
SELECT * FROM earthquakes WHERE milliseconds > 0 OFFSET 400 LIMIT 200
```

Along with that, also return the maximum number of results, so you can build a proper UI on the front-end:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM earthquakes WHERE milliseconds > 0
```

Then, you just display this and your page controls and you will be all set.

Comment: hmm this is a good idea but i have a doubt....do you think is possible to show the next 200 results when first 200 results are loaded ? I don't want split the page in more pages.... sorry for my english

Comment: Yes, you could just have JavaScript make subsequent calls after loading one set, so it'd progressively load. That's be the same approach for the SQL, just your JavaScript making the calls at a different time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` and `offset` to implement pagination.

However, you can split your use case into "Exploring few earthquakes" and "Exploring many". Thus, the first can return a complete list with all the details, and the other will return, say, a heat map. The heatmap is generated on the backend and does not involve sending all the rows to the fronted. 
One use case or another is triggered by the number of rows matching the filter.